# Динамическая фильтрация на сайте FastAPI

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi

Всем привет, мне надо реализовать фильтрацию на сайте, у меня используется MongoDB. Дело в том что у меня есть несколько массивов. old_fliters, где выводятся всевозможные значения всех фильтров, есть массив filters, где должны отображается доступные фильтры, когда у меня было всего два фильтра возраст и бренд то работала такая логика если выбрали бренд и возраст:

в каталоге показываем бренд and возраст
в фильтрах показываем бренд or возраст

когда фильтров стало больше двух такая логика перестала работать, помогите пожалуйста решить данную проблему какую логику надо использовать, но фронтенде, массив filters отображается жирным шрифтом (доступен к выбору), массив old_fliters для сравнения с filters, то есть чего нет в массиве filters, но есть в массиве old_fliters на фронтенде затемняется.

Вот наглядный пример я выбираю материал картон, страну китай и с такой логикой как выше остается возраст 0+ который есть или у китая или у картона, но если пересечь все три фильтра то таких продуктов нет.

```
from math import ceil

from fastapi import HTTPException, APIRouter, Query

route_catalog_test = APIRouter()

from database import my_collection
from enum import Enum
from typing import Optional


class SortOrder(str, Enum):
    price_asc = "price_asc"
    price_desc = "price_desc"
    price_disc = "price_disc"
    new = "new"
    default = "default"
    popular = "popular"

def extract_age(s):
    if s is None:
        return int("99")  # Большое значение для None
    return int(s[:-1])

@route_catalog_test.get("/catalog")
async def filter_products(
    age: list[str] = Query(None, description="Возраст"),
    brand: list[str] = Query(None, description="Бренд"),
    category: str = Query(None, description="Категория"),
    material: list[str] = Query(None, description="Материал"),
    country: list[str] = Query(None, description="Страна"),
    size: list[str] = Query(None, description="Размер"),
    weight: list[str] = Query(None, description="Вес"),
    sex: list[str] = Query(None, description="Пол"),
    price_from: int = Query(None, description="Минимальная цена"),
    price_to: int = Query(None, description="Максимальная цена"),
    page: int = Query(1, gt=0),
    limit: int = Query(50, gt=0),
    offset: int = Query(0),
    sort: Optional[SortOrder] = Query(SortOrder.default),
    # params: dict = Body({}, description="Дополнительные параметры фильтрации"),
):
    # Формируем фильтр для запроса к базе данных

proj3 = {
    "_id": 0,
    "category": 1,
    "brand": 1,
    "brand_slug": 1,
    "category_slug": 1,
    "params.age": 1,
    "params.country": 1,
    "params.material": 1,
    "params.size": 1,
    "params.sex": 1,
    "params.weight": 1,
    "params.gabarit": 1,
    "price": 1
}

old_filter = my_collection.find({}, proj3)

unique_categories_1 = set()
unique_brands_1 = set()
unique_ages_1 = set()
unique_country_1 = set()
params_means = {}
min_price_found_1 = float("inf")  # Задаем начальное значение как бесконечность
max_price_found_1 = 0  # Задаем начальное значение как 0

# Обработка продуктов и добавление уникальных значений в множества
for product_old in old_filter:
    unique_categories_1.add((product_old["category"], product_old["category_slug"]))
    unique_brands_1.add((product_old["brand"], product_old["brand_slug"]))
    # unique_ages_1.add(product_old["params"]["age"])
    unique_country_1.add(product_old["params"]["country"])

    params = product_old.get("params", {})
    for key, value in params.items():
        if key not in params_means:
            params_means[key] = set()
        params_means[key].add(value)

    price = product_old.get("price", 0)  # Получаем цену товара (если есть)
    if price < min_price_found_1:
        min_price_found_1 = price
    if price > max_price_found_1:
        max_price_found_1 = price

old_filters = {
    "all_categories": sorted([{"title": title, "slug": slug} for title, slug in unique_categories_1], key=lambda x: x["title"]),
    "all_brands": sorted([{"title": title, "slug": slug} for title, slug in unique_brands_1], key=lambda x: x["title"]),
    # "all_ages": sorted(unique_ages_1, key=extract_age),
    # "params_means_1": ({"country":unique_country_1}),
    "params_means": params_means,
    "mini_price": min_price_found_1,
    "maxi_price": max_price_found_1,
}

filters_all = {}

projection = {
    "title": 1,
    "title_slug": 1,
    "price": 1,
    'discount_price': 1,
    "category": 1,
    "brand": 1,
    "age": 1,
    "brand_slug": 1,
    "category_slug": 1,
    "images": 1,
    "params": 1,
    "labels": 1,
    "upload_date": 1
}

if age and not isinstance(age, list):
    raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid 'age' parameter. Expected a list.")
if brand and not isinstance(brand, list):
    raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid 'brand' parameter. Expected a list.")

# Check if 'age' and 'brand' lists are not empty
if age and len(age) == 0:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Empty 'age' parameter. Expected a non-empty list.")
if brand and len(brand) == 0:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Empty 'brand' parameter. Expected a non-empty list.")

if age:
    filters_all["params.age"] = {"$in": age}
if brand:
    filters_all["brand_slug"] = {"$in": brand}
if category:
    filters_all["category_slug"] = category
if country:
    filters_all["params.country"] = {"$in": country}
if material:
    filters_all["params.material"] = {"$in": material}
if size:
    filters_all["params.size"] = {"$in": size}
if weight:
    filters_all["params.weight"] = {"$in": weight}
if sex:
    filters_all["params.sex"] = {"$in": sex}

if price_from and price_to:
    filters_all["price"] = {"$gte": price_from, "$lte": price_to}
elif price_from:
    filters_all["price"] = {"$gte": price_from}
elif price_to:
    filters_all["price"] = {"$lte": price_to}

# Запрашиваем продукты из базы данных с применением всех фильтров
products_with_all_filters = my_collection.find(filters_all, projection)

proj2 = {
    "_id": 0,
    "category": 1,
    "brand": 1,
    "brand_slug": 1,
    "category_slug": 1,
    "params.age": 1,
    "params.country": 1,
    "params.material": 1,
    "params.size": 1,
    "params.sex": 1,
    "params.weight": 1,
    "params.gabarit": 1,
    "price": 1
}

# Запрашиваем продукты из базы данных с применением хотя бы одного из фильтров
or_filters = []
if age:
    or_filters.append({"params.age": {"$in": age}})
if brand:
    or_filters.append({"brand_slug": {"$in": brand}})
if category:
    or_filters.append({"category_slug": category})
if country:
    or_filters.append({"params.country_slug": {"$in": country}})
if material:
    or_filters.append({"params.material": {"$in": material}})
if size:
    or_filters.append({"params.size_slug": {"$in": size}})
if weight:
    or_filters.append({"params.weight_slug": {"$in": weight}})
if sex:
    or_filters.append({"params.sex_slug": {"$in": sex}})

if or_filters:
    products_with_any_filter = my_collection.find({"$or": or_filters}, proj2)
else:
    # Если нет фильтров, вернуть все продукты
    products_with_any_filter = my_collection.find({}, proj2)

unique_categories = set()
unique_brands = set()
unique_ages = set()
unique_country = set()
params_means = {}
min_price_found = float("inf")  # Задаем начальное значение как бесконечность
max_price_found = 0  # Задаем начальное значение как 0

# Обработка продуктов и добавление уникальных значений в множества
for product in products_with_any_filter:
    unique_categories.add((product["category"], product["category_slug"]))
    unique_brands.add((product["brand"], product["brand_slug"]))
    # unique_ages.add(product["params"]["age"])

    params = product.get("params", {})
    for key, value in params.items():
        if key not in params_means:
            params_means[key] = set()
        params_means[key].add(value)

    unique_country.add(product["params"]["country"])
    price = product.get("price", 0)  # Получаем цену товара (если есть)
    if price < min_price_found:
        min_price_found = price
    if price > max_price_found:
        max_price_found = price

# Формирование словаря filters без повторенийf
filters = {
    "categories": sorted([{"title": title, "slug": slug} for title, slug in unique_categories], key=lambda x: x["title"]),
    "brands": sorted([{"title": title, "slug": slug} for title, slug in unique_brands], key=lambda x: x["title"]),
    # "ages": sorted(unique_ages, key=extract_age),
    # "params_means_1": ({"country":unique_country}),
    "params_means": params_means,
    "min_price": min_price_found,
    "max_price": max_price_found,
}

if brand and not age and not category and not country and not material and not size and not weight and not sex:
    filters["brands"] = old_filters["all_brands"]

if age and not brand and not category and not country and not material and not size and not weight and not sex:
    # filters["ages"] = old_filters["all_ages"]
    filters["params_means"]["age"] = old_filters["params_means"]["age"]

if country and not age and not brand and not category and not material and not size and not weight and not sex:
    filters["params_means"]["country"] = old_filters["params_means"]["country"]

if material and not age and not brand and not category and not country and not size and not weight and not sex:
    filters["params_means"]["material"] = old_filters["params_means"]["material"]

if size and not age and not brand and not category and not material and not country and not weight and not sex:
    filters["params_means"]["size"] = old_filters["params_means"]["size"]

if weight and not age and not brand and not category and not material and not size and not country and not sex:
    filters["params_means"]["weight"] = old_filters["params_means"]["weight"]

if sex and not age and not brand and not category and not material and not size and not country and not weight:
    filters["params_means"]["sex"] = old_filters["params_means"]["sex"]

sorted_files = list(products_with_all_filters)

if sort == SortOrder.price_asc:
    sorted_files = sorted(sorted_files, key=lambda x: x.get("price", float("inf")))
elif sort == SortOrder.price_desc:
    sorted_files = sorted(sorted_files, key=lambda x: x.get("price", 0), reverse=True)
elif sort == SortOrder.price_disc:  # Сортировка сначала по наличию скидки, затем по цене
    sorted_files = sorted(sorted_files, key=lambda x: (x.get("discount_price") == 0, x.get("price", 0)))
elif sort == SortOrder.popular:
    sorted_files = sorted(sorted_files, key=lambda x: x.get("popularity", 0), reverse=True)

total_count = len(sorted_files)
start_index = (page - 1) * limit + offset
end_index = start_index + limit
paged_files = sorted_files[start_index:end_index]

data = list(paged_files)

if not paged_files:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="No products found for the selected category")

total_pages = ceil(total_count / limit)

# Возвращаем результаты запросов в виде словаря с продуктами
return {
    "test": {"$and": filters},
    "total_count": total_count,
    "total_pages": total_pages,
    "current_page": page,
    "total_products": len(paged_files),
    "data": data,
    "products_with_any_filter": list(products_with_any_filter),
    "filters": filters,
    "old_filter": old_filters
}
```

Отображаемые фильтры у меня обрабатываются тут

```
or_filters = []
if age:
    or_filters.append({"params.age": {"$in": age}})
if brand:
    or_filters.append({"brand_slug": {"$in": brand}})
if category:
    or_filters.append({"category_slug": category})
if country:
    or_filters.append({"params.country_slug": {"$in": country}})
if material:
    or_filters.append({"params.material": {"$in": material}})
if size:
    or_filters.append({"params.size_slug": {"$in": size}})
if weight:
    or_filters.append({"params.weight_slug": {"$in": weight}})
if sex:
    or_filters.append({"params.sex_slug": {"$in": sex}})

if or_filters:
    products_with_any_filter = my_collection.find({"$or": or_filters}, proj2)
else:
    # Если нет фильтров, вернуть все продукты
    products_with_any_filter = my_collection.find({}, proj2)
```